# Draw a cyclone in Python with a given number of cycles?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zelle-graphics

I can't seem to draw a cyclone with an inputted number of cycles. The code is supposed to have the user click a start and and end point, and then a cyclone will be drawn with inputted cycles from start point to end point.

```
from math import *
from graphics import *

def main():
    win = GraphWin("Drawing a Cyclone",600,450)            
    win.setCoords(0,0,600,450)                             
    msg = "Please enter the number of cycles, and click the start and end positions in the window."
    Text(Point(300, 438), msg).draw(win)
    Text(Point(65,415),"# of cycles:").draw(win)
    inbox =Entry(Point(130,415),5)
    inbox.draw(win)


    start=win.getMouse()
    start.setFill("red")
    start.draw(win)
    stop=win.getMouse()
    stop.setFill("red")
    stop.draw(win)

    cycles=eval(inbox.getText())
    radius = 0                                                 
    length = sqrt((stop.x-start.x)**2+(stop.y-start.y)**2)  
    step_radius = length / (120*cycles)
    radian = atan((stop.y-start.y)/(stop.x-start.x))
    initial_angle = int(degrees(radian))

    for i in (0, cycles*360, 3):
        radius = radius + step_radius
        theta=radians(initial_angle + (360*cycles*i)+3*i)
        stop.x = start.x + radius*cos(theta)
        stop.y = start.y + radius*sin(theta)
        line=Line(start,stop)
        line.draw(win)
        start.x=stop.x
        start.y=stop.y


    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

main()
```

[This is what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wkKq.png)

[This is what I'm supposed to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8uOW.png)

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. And your question should describe what this code currently does so we don't have to spend time running your code to see what it does wrong. (Also, not everyone has the `graphics` module).

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the bulk of your problems center around this code:

```
theta=radians(initial_angle + (360*cycles*i)+3*i)
stop.x = start.x + radius*cos(theta)
stop.y = start.y + radius*sin(theta)
```

The `i` variable is already tracing circles so `theta` should be the radians equivalent of `i` with an adjustment for the initial angle but you've done lots of additional math with `i`.  Also, the stop position should be a function of the `cos()` and `sin()` calculations corrected for the origin of the figure but you use `start` which was the origin originally but is a moving target inside the loop.

One way to go about debugging this is to set the cycles to 1 and set `radius = length` instead of `radius += step_radius`.  This will give you a simple circle to work out issues of proper positioning, radius, etc. without the added complication of the spiral.  Then add back the spiral.

Something more along these lines might give you some ideas what to fix:

```
from math import *
from graphics import *

DEGREES_PER_STEP = 3

win = GraphWin("Drawing a Cyclone", 600, 450)
win.setCoords(0, 0, 600, 450)
msg = "Please enter the number of cycles, and click the start and end positions in the window."
Text(Point(300, 438), msg).draw(win)
Text(Point(65, 415), "# of cycles:").draw(win)
inbox = Entry(Point(130, 415), 5)
inbox.draw(win)

origin = win.getMouse()
origin.setFill("green")
origin.draw(win)
target = win.getMouse()
target.setFill("red")
target.draw(win)

cycles = float(inbox.getText())
radius = 0
length = sqrt((target.x - origin.x) ** 2 + (target.y - origin.y) ** 2)
step_radius = length / (cycles * 360 / DEGREES_PER_STEP)
initial_angle = atan((target.y - origin.y) / (target.x - origin.x))

start = Point(origin.x, origin.y)

for i in range(0, int(cycles * 360), DEGREES_PER_STEP):
    radius += step_radius
    theta = radians(i) + initial_angle  # initial angle already in radians
    stop = Point(origin.x + radius * cos(theta), origin.y + radius * sin(theta))
    line = Line(start, stop)
    line.draw(win)
    start = stop

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

This still has issues getting the initial angle correct in some quadrants but that's something you can work on.  Also, if you click the points just right, you can generate a divide by zero so you'll want to deal with that as well:

[image]

Note that although `from graphics import *` is commonly done, `from math import *` is riskier -- for example, `math.pow()` overwrites Python's built-in `pow()` and the two are not identical.  Consider a safer import.